# How can remove data from table 1 if data (id) exists in table 2 but if table 2 is empty delete all in table 1?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this sql for my Postgresql db:

```
  DELETE FROM table1
  USING table2
  WHERE table1.id = table2.table2_id
  AND table1.id = $1
```

An issue is that, when there's no data in table2 with the condition `table1.id = table2.table2_id` it won't remove anything from any table.

Whereas, I want it to remove data from `table1` always, regardless whether or not there's data for `table1.id = table2.table2_id` in `table2`

How do I have to twist the script?

Comment: Then use `delete from table1;`

Comment: @pivoche . . . If you don't care about `table2`, why are you including it in the query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff where did I say that I don't care about table2?

Comment: @pivoche . . . Use cascading constraints.  Postgres `delete` deletes from one table, not multiple tables.

Comment: Gordon is correct. In Postgres (and SQL in general) a `DELETE` statement only affects a single table. So the statement you have shown will only delete from `table1` it won't touch `table2`. Are you trying to remove all rows from both tables?

Comment: I tried to fix the title so it's easier to understand I guess user wants to delete from table 1 if id exists in table 2, but if table 2 is empty they need to delete all in table 1.

Comment: @pivoche . . . Please show the reference where Postgres allows delete to delete from multiple tables.  Here is the documentation for your reference:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Gordon is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

```
   DELETE FROM table1
   USING table2
   WHERE table1.id = coalesce(table2.table2_id,table1.id)
   AND table1.id = $1
```

I never used PostgreSQL, but if table2 has no reference, you have to add a null clause, which coalesce does this way... I think.